# Should I use size classes to port to iPad or create separate storyboards?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I'm looking to use size classes for the first time with my iOS8+ project to port my iPhone app to iPad. I've used autolayout to create my storyboard but I intend on using a UISplitViewController for the iPad to make use of the extra screen real estate.

From my googling on the subject it appears size classes may be limited to changing constraints rather than changing the type of controller used? I've not read this specifically but cannot find any example of changing the type of controller used. Are size classes not usable for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size classes allow you to enable / disable a constraint based on the size of the device. There is no facility to run conditional logic. If you need a fundamentally different UI, you will need separate storyboards. Having 2 completely different UI's in the same storyboard, toggled on / off via size classes will get very complex, very quickly. Size classes are best used for small changes.

That being said the `UISplitViewController` is more complex than you think. You can hide / show the detail in varying ways using size classes. This can then be used as the starting point for both iPhone / iPad and toggle it on / off as need be using size classes (assuming that the rest of the app will remain largely the same).

I'd suggest doing more research on the topic. Try reading article such as this [one](http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/). It will then be up to you to decide if your use case needs 2 sets of storyboards or 1 set with size classes.